# Ada: How to manage Data_error exception when getting integers

Tags: exception, input, integer, ada

I'm trying to make the user select a mode from the menu for example

1. Eat
2. Drink
3. Sleep

Now I can get an integer input by using the call

```
ada.integer_text_io.get(integer_variable);
```

The main problem here is that if I insert a non digit string(such as a character string) the following exception is raised

```
raised ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR : a-tiinio.adb:89 instantiated at a-inteio.ads:18
```

I've tried receiving a character, check if it is a integer, then convert it into a integer, but then I realized that I need to get inputs for integer larger than 1 digits, so the character method won't work.

If I receive a string, then I can't check to see if it is a integer or not(unless i scan through the whole string to see if all its characters are integer...)

Is there another solution other than scanning the whole string?
Or perhaps a exception handling technique that might keep the program from terminating and ask again for a proper integer?

-CH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much all the standard ways to parse a string into a scalar value of some kind in Ada will produce an exception of some kind when/if an invalid string is read. There isn't anything wrong with that. Just handle the exception.

Even if you wrote your own string parsing to integer routines, you'd have to somehow handle the situation where the user entered an invalid string. Right?

I guess the only "technique" involved is that you can put exception handlers on subroutines, or even on `declare ... begin ... end` blocks that you put inline in your code. This way only the code within the block is aborted. Generally I prefer to see subroutines used. So you'd get something like:

```ada
function User_Integer return Integer is
begin
    loop
        begin
            ada.integer_text_io.get(integer_variable);
            return integer_variable;
        exception
            when ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR =>
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Try a number from 1 to 3, Sherlock");
                Print_Menu;
        end;
    end loop;
end User_Integer;
```

Now, this being the case, for quick-and-dirty Ada menus I generally don't do numeric menus like above. Instead, make an enumerated type. That way you can print the menu options using a `'image` in a loop through the menu type, and Ada will handle the text parsing when you use `'value` or `Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO`.

```ada
type Menu_Selection_Option is (Eat, Drink, Sleep);
package Menu_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO (Menu_Selection_Option);
function User_Selection return Integer is
begin
    loop
        declare
            Selection : Menu_Selection_Option;
        begin
            Menu_IO.Get(Selection);
            return Selection;
        exception
            when ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR =>
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Unrecognized option. Try again Sherlock");
                Print_Menu;
        end;
    end loop;
end User_Selection;
```

The nice thing about this is that you don't have to change your menu-printing code or your parsing code when the list of menu options changes.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! But do I need to have another declare, begin and end within the function's loop or can i just leave out the declare and begin part?

Comment: Wow! I'll keep the enumeration method in mind the next time I program in Ada! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm still caught in the past, but I'm always a little leery of directly invoking an enumeration or numeric I/O package instantiation's Get when dealing with _console_ input.  Compilers in the past have been inconsistent in how they handle "clearing" the interactive input buffer when a bad data entry is made.  Dealing with this inconsistency is how the Get_Line/convert idiom got established years ago, because all the Ada compilers appeared to at least handle Get_Line consistently.  But maybe that's gotten better and more consistent lately.

Comment: @Heartinpiece - When an exception handler gets run, the block it is in will terminate. If you put the exception handler at the function level, the function would end after the handler code finished (and you'd damn well better have a `return` statement in there). That isn't what you want to happen here, as this is an error condidtion so there is no good value to return. So yeah, the declare block is sadly kinda needed here.

Comment: @Marc C - Actually, generally I'm with you. If I were coding from scratch, I'd use Get_Line and Menu_Selection_Option'Value instead of Enumeration_IO. The main reason is that you can do more complicated things with it (like print out the invalid input the user gave you in your exception handler). However, this was closer to what the OQ was trying to do, and it ought to work.

Answer (score 4):

The predominant Ada programming idiom for requesting user input of this sort uses Get_Line:

```
procedure Get_Line(Item : out String;   Last : out Natural);
```

or

```
function Get_Line return String;
```

Now that the user's response is in a string you can do a quick scan for non-numeric characters, or use the Integer'Value attribute to convert it to an integer (wrapping the invocation in a suitable exception handler).  For example:

```ada
loop
   Put_Line("What do you want to do?");
   Display_Options;
   declare
      What_To_Do : Positive;
      Response : String(1..20);
      Last     : Natural;
   begin
      Get_Line(Response, Last);
      exit when Last = 0;

      What_To_Do := Integer'Value(Response(1 .. Last));  --' Buggy highlight fix
      Go_Do_Something(What_To_Do);

   exception
      when Data_Error =>
         Put_Line("Invalid response, try again...");
   end;
end loop;
```

The added advantage of this idiom is that you can accept non-numeric input as well, such as 'Q' for Quit, or "Quit"; and also do any character preprocessing, like up-casing, that might be needed.

Comment: Thanks! got my program running properly!

Comment: Should be : Integer'Value(Response(Response'first .. Last)); as its probably implementation dependent whether the string is indexed from 0 or 1 or something else...

Comment: @NWS: No, since Response is declared in this example with an index explicitly ranging from 1 .. 20, Response'First is 1, there is nothing implementation dependent about it.  And while the index range of a string can vary, that variance is a result of how it is declared by the application, it is _not_ dependent on any kind of compiler or language dependency.  Although, when a String variable is utilized as an argument, with no explicit bounds information provided, it typically is better then to use the String attributes ('First, 'Last, etc.) to access its range indices.

Comment: Correct when you are using this get_Line and declaration of Response, but in general, when indexing strings, dont assume any starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the exception, either within a loop to repeatedly ask for input until an integer is entered, or towards the end to exit gracefully...

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could implement the exception within a loop!! Works fine now!